# My Gmail labels window has collapsed, how can I bring it back?

Tags: gmail

My labels window has collapsed - horizontally, not vertically - and so now I can only see the inbox and starred labels.  I have tried all the options listed - I can see the 'Meet' tab, I have tried clicking on the 'hamburger' tab, but this is more for a vertical collapse as opposed to a horizontal collapse. I cant clear this so far.

Does anyone have a clear and simple fix for this frustrating quirk that has suddenly appeared?

Comment: Can you share a screenshot?

Comment: How many labels would there be in the list?

Answer (score -1):

In Gmail, go to Settings --> All Settings --> Inbox. The "Categories" section controls which labels are viewed horizontally as if they are separate inboxes.

Note: Go to Settings --> All Settings --> Labels to edit your labels.

Comment: Hello David, thank you. I have tried that, it doesnt work. If I scroll down the 'window' using the slide on the right of the window I can see all the labels. It is only allowing me to see the 'inbox' label, and 'starred' label. I am trying to expand the window to see all of the labels- as I could this time last week. I have also noticed that the arrows that should allow the window to expand at the bottom of the window ( - it appears when you hover over the 'dash' above MEET) also seems to be disabled and therefore not allowing the inbox window (immediately below COMPOSE) to expand. Strange??